# ASP.NET + MVC4 - "faking" a model? working without a datatable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not an ASP.NET programmer, but, as it happens in life, I had to do some minor projects using it. Now came another one in which I have to implement some custom solutions and I haven't figured it out yet - I need some tip or maybe a piece of advice like "don't go that way" ;)

Previously it was simple - there was a table in DB, there was an adequate model and a view that worked with it - worked like charm. Now it's a little bit more complicated.

The "site" is going to contain, shortly and generally speaking, a survey - but a fully configurable one, unfortunately. In another product there's gonna be a configuration manager that will allow user to define pages, block types, questions, steps and so on and will generate an XML.

For the time being, in accordance with the specification, in the site's database I'm going to have only one table which will contain just a key and the XML generated by the configurator (and maybe some additional, not important information). Now - I need to parse this XML and build the site containing pages and other elements corresponding to it.

And that WOULD not be a problem, but I don't really know how to work that way using asp.net + mvc and can't find any piece of advice that would help me anyhow. Should I create an object that would somehow fake being a model and allow me to work for example on a dataset generated from XML? Or just create a model of the mentioned table and work with the XML directly on the view (I don't like even such an idea itself)? Or - having to do something like that - just give up on MVC and use only "clear" ASP.NET? Or maybe something else?

I'll be very grateful for any help.

And I hope I described what I need understandably ;)

Comment: Please highlight any specific issues you're having trouble with. Can't you: create a new MVC project, parse XML, loop through objects to create form elements based on their properties, determining the model format so you can read the filled in, POSTed survey? Did you try anything, are you having a concrete problem on any subject?

Comment: From what you listed, the problem would be "determining the model format so you can read the filled in, POSTed survey". I don't have much experience with MVC and previously I only worked with determined, "changeless" models with constant set of fields adequate to fields in datatable. Now I need to create something that would allow me to work with dynamic content dependent on the xml. My friend's just given me a hint of using the ViewBag and I'll give it a try, but I don't know yet if that will do the trick.

Comment: In that case, you can take a look at using a `dynamic` model.

Answer (score 1):

If the XML documents have a schema defined then you can easily generate a class that matches the document using the [xsd.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx). The document can then be deserialized into an instance of that class using existing functionality in the .Net framework. Just google .Net Xml serialization :-)

Now, if you don't have a schema you could create one if you are sure that you know the format of the Xml. Alternatively you could create a class that matches the format you expect to get and then parse the Xml manually. This last option is much more work, so I wouldn't recommend it.

In any case, the class you end up with should contain all the data you need from the Xml document and can then be used as the Model in your MVC page. As long as you can use the standard Xml deserialization technique then this should be quite easy and painless.